# Drop Unique mysql for two fields

Tags: mysql

Hi recently I made mysql two fields unique and now I'm unable to drop them
I've add them like

> ```
> ALTER TABLE  `user_subscription` ADD UNIQUE (
> `user_id` ,
> `status`
> );
> ```

But Now i want to undo this, any idea?

Comment: you want to drop the unique key, or the fields themselves?

Comment: Above code is for adding unique index what you have tried to drop ? also post error details too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index name using:

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM user_subscription;
```

Then drop it:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON user_subscription;
```